# How to keep whitepaces between words in algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am new to LaTeX. When I tried to write an algorithm all spaces between words get removed after `\gets`. See the image.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Filtering lexicon file}
\label{algo1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $Lex$ \gets read the whole lexicon file.$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

How to keep the spaces between words "read the whole lexicon file". Thank you.

Comment: You get errors from that input, because `\gets` is a math symbol. Adding a trailing `$` is not the solution. Maybe `$\mathit{Lex}\gets$ read the whole lexicon file.`

Comment: @egreg post it as a answer. $\mathit{Lex}\gets$ read the whole lexicon file. is the correct answer. I will make it my answer.

Comment: @NahidHossain I believe you should extend the example, so that it's possible to give advice also for other parts of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get a correction and it may depend on other usage

I am not saying these are more correct but the simplest is to remove the $ as per line 1 but that will change the font upright so see some alternatives with italics
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Filtering lexicon file}
\label{algo1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $Lex \gets $ read the whole lexicon file.
\State $Lex \gets~read~the~whole~lexicon~file.$
\State $Lex \gets \textit{read the whole lexicon file.}$
\State $Lex \gets $ \textit {read the whole lexicon file.}
\State $Lex \gets $ {\itshape read the whole lexicon file.} % as recommended by Barbara Beeton This switch should be bound
\State $Lex \gets $ read the whole lexicon file. % note none of the above have affected this line

here is another line
\end{algorithmic}
and another
\end{algorithm}
```

and another
\end{document}

Comment: While it may work okay here, i.e., get turned off at the end of the line (I'm not sure, and can't test), an "ungrouped" `\itshape` will persist in other situations, and should be used with caution.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am no TeXnician so accept that all my suggestions could be wrong its just that in my editor(s) they worked as per their fonts, I accept they may likely behave badly in other engines/locales

Comment: If I were trying to test the persistence, I would repeat at the end the first instance of the test line (the one with no style change after the second `$`) to make sure it doesn't become italic. (Sorry for the noise; I would have tested if I could, but have no TeX installation available.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton in my laymans terms as far as I can tell \itshape  persists with or without braces until it is "broken" by the \end{algorithmic} thus could affect following lines within that environment

Comment: Given that you've determined that it persists, it would be best to add braces to that step -- `{\itshape ... }`.  Font "switches" like `\itshape` are intended to be used in localized situations.  (An environment like `algorithmic` is almost always defined as a local group.)

Comment: yes unbound the next line is italic (beneficial ? not to be repeated :-) bound as you suggest next line reverts to upright I will amend answer to "better" it